# How to listen to angular 2 events MANUALLY on a dependency injected instance?

Tags: typescript, angular

If i have a component like

```
@Component({selector: 'todo-cmp'})
class TodoCmp {
  @Input() model;
  @Output() complete = new EventEmitter(); // TypeScript supports initializing fields

  onCompletedButton() {
    this.complete.next(); // this fires an event
  }
}
```

and in another component I get a copy of it through DI as in:

```
...
 class SomeOtherClass(){
    constructor(todoCmp:TodoCmp){
   // how do I listen to 
   ...
 }
 ...
```

How do I add an event listener manually inside "SomeOtherClass" and listen to any click events fired from the depenendcy injected instance of ToDoCmp..

something like todoCmp.addEventListener('complete',function(e){});

maybe?  or something better in ng2?

TX

Sean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `EventEmitter.next()` has been `EventEmitter.emit()` since alpha-45 or so.

Second, the method you're looking for is `.subscribe()`

```
class SomeOtherClass(){
  constructor(todoCmp:TodoCmp){
     todoCmp.complete.subscribe((result)=>{
        //result == arg passed into emit()  
     }))
 }
```

Note that this information  is readily available in [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html) - you should really check those out, as `EventEmitter` is much more capable than the event listeners you're used to.

Comment: thx yes I just figured out now its rxjs so all good,  tx for the answer

Comment: @born2net if this answers your questions can you please accept it.

Comment: sorry, how do I "accept" it? I did mark it +1 ... but how can I accept it as the correct answer? is there a button for this? I don't see it StackEx